# How to remove password confirmation field in django UserCreationForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have created a UserCreationForm as follow:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1']

        exclude = ['password2']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserRegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # for fieldname in ['password2']:
        self.fields['password2'].help_text = None
        self.fields['password1'].help_text = None
        self.fields['username'].help_text = None
```

However I am trying to remove Password Confirmation field from the register form, but so far couldn't find any solution for that. Do you know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can delete `password2` in `__init__` method:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1']


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserRegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        del self.fields['password2']
        self.fields['password1'].help_text = None
        self.fields['username'].help_text = None
```

Password confirmation is verified by the [**`clean_password2()`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c6b07627fcb5d1c8d2082714ef5adb63bee6cf4c/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L106) method.

> ```
>  def clean_password2(self):
>     password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
>     password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
>     if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
>         raise forms.ValidationError(
>             self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
>             code='password_mismatch',
>         )
>     return password2
> ```

**Update**

---

So as @AbdulAzizBarkat pointed out **`password2`** also used in [**`_post_clean()`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c6b07627fcb5d1c8d2082714ef5adb63bee6cf4c/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L116) method.

If you use `password2` in your form and don't use password confirmation. Chances are that `password2` and `password1` don't match, and you will not pass validation. Because `password2` must be also pass validation in `_post_clean` method.

So use:

```
del self.fields['password2']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How about the verification, does it ok based on django  policy as well?

Comment: @J2015, The verification happens in `clean_password2()` method.  So if you just delete this password2 field, everything will work. I updated my answer with additional info.

Comment: @NKSM `password2` is also used in `_post_clean` you would need to override that too... It would just be better to rewrite the whole form.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, Yes, it is true, but verification is only done if a password2 is provided. See  https://github.com/django/django/blob/c6b07627fcb5d1c8d2082714ef5adb63bee6cf4c/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L116

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, So if you delete `password2` field , it will be work.

Comment: @NKSM yes there is `password = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')` and then `if password:` but that is the problem. `password_validation.validate_password(password, self.instance)` is validating the provided password with all of the password validators set in the settings. If you don't override it you skip those validations!

Comment: @NKSM So then I should add `def clean_password2(self):` to the forms methods? Because even without it, it's working after adding `del self.fields['password2']`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, Ok, but if you don't use `password2` it will be work. In `_post_clean` it simple validate `password2`.

Comment: @NKSM It validates the provided password using `password2`. It will work **but** you would have skipped validating with the password validators set in the settings (Minimum length, similarity etc. those validations). It is not validating `password2`. It has already confirmed `password1` and `password2` are the same and now checks if the password provided is actually a valid password. Consider that you just enter `1` as the password. This implementation would consider it valid.

Comment: @J2015, I would use `del self.fields['password2']` in `__init__`.